# How to catch constraint violation inside the resultset loop?

Tags: java, jdbc

I was working on a servlet that will generate a unique code and update that in a mySQL database.
Now, in that, I want to catch any exception thrown in case that unique code already exists in the mySQL table and generate a new code and try updating the database. The problem is I want to do this WITHIN the for loop itself. The code is as follows:

```
    try
    {
    connection = datasource.getConnection();
    SQLUpdate = "INSERT INTO Voucher_dump VALUES( '"+unique_code+"','08-10-2011 04:48:48','0')";
      PreparedStatement ps1 = connection.prepareStatement(SQLUpdate);
      ps1.executeUpdate();
      ResultSet r = ps1.getResultSet(); // this is where I'm checking if it's a duplicate
      if(r==null)
          out.println("This is a duplicate");
      else out.println("Updated");
      trial12= "08-10-2011 04:48:480.03999855056924717a";
      SQLUpdate = "INSERT INTO Voucher_dump VALUES( '"+trial12+"','08-10-2011 04:48:48','0')";

      ps1 = connection.prepareStatement(SQLUpdate);
      ps1.executeUpdate();
      r = ps1.getResultSet();
      if(r==null)
          out.println("This is a duplicate");
      else out.println("Updated");

    }
    catch (SQLException sqle)
    {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't want to wait till the end of the entire loop to catch the SQLException (I have already defined this key in mySQL as primary). The moment, the result comes back as a duplicate entry, I want to re-generate this key and attempt the update again.My output for this particular code is coming blank on my output page (all other parameters are showing correctly). Neither is "This is a duplicate" displayed nor is "Updated". Maybe, ResultSet is not the best way to do it. Could you guys give me some advice on what would be the best way forward ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some advice in no particular order:

1. Close the connection in a finally block.
2. Close statements individually if you'll be creating many of them before closing the connection. ("Many" is defined by your DBAs.)
3. Format your code.
4. Don't use stdout and/or stderr from real code. Pick a logging framework.
5. Consider using some helper classes to simplify (and correct) your database access, like Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html).
6. Make sure to include relevant context when you post example code.

Due to #6, I don't know what `out` is, but I suspect the reason you're not seeing anything is that you're inserting a duplicate value with the first statement, which will cause a SQLException from that line, not at `getResultSet()`, where you seem to expect it. Since the error is written to stdout, it'll show up in your server logs somewhere, but nothing will be written to `out`. I'm not sure why you think `getResultSet()` will return null or not null depending on whether there was a constraint violation. Take a look at the [javadoc for that method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet%28%29).

**Update:** 7. As BalusC points out, **never, ever** concatenate a string directly into a JDBC Statment. Use PreparedStatment's [placeholders and `set*` methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). For info on SQL injection, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Potential SQL injection hole could also be added to the list.

Comment: @BalusC: Ouch. Good catch. I was up too late last night.

Answer (score 1):

How about this code?

```
try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName);
            System.out.println("Connected to the database");
            int i = 1;                                     //get the unique code
            boolean isInserted = false;
            while (!isInserted) {
                try {
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test values (?)");
                    preparedStatement.setInt(1, i);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    isInserted = true;
                } catch (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {   //Catch the particular exception which throws error on unique constraint. This may depend on Java/MySQL your version 
                    i++;                         //get the next unique code
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: That seems to solve the poster's problem, but please don't catch  `Exception`. That may unintentionally catch and silence Exceptions other than the ones you want to handle. Catch the most specific subclass of Exception instead.

Comment: Hi..thanks for all your help....will try it out and let you know.. Ryan, I had just put up that part of the code where I was facing issues (1) & (2) had already been done....will take of the others as well....thanks a lot !

Comment: You are right @S.L.Barth. Will take care of it in future. Thank you for your valuable feedback.